# cocos2d-x how to repeat a NPOT image

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I want a background image repeat-x, but do not want to change the image's witdh and height.

```
    CCSize s = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();
    CCSprite* sprite = CCSprite::create("sprite.png"); // the image size is 256 * 224, so the height is non power of 2.
    CCRect spriteRect = sprite->getTextureRect();
    spriteRect.size.width = s.width;
    pSkyBg->setTextureRect(skyRect);

    ccTexParams tp = { GL_LINEAR, GL_LINEAR, GL_REPEAT, GL_REPEAT};
    sprite->getTexture()->setTexParameters(&tp);

    sprite->setPosition((ccp(0, s.height)));
    sprite->setAnchorPoint(ccp(0, 1));
    addChild(sprite, 0);
```

there is some wrong. who can help me!  thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image's height and width must be power of 2. Obviously 224 is not.

Comment: Can't we use GL_WRAP ?

Answer (score 1):

It works perfect with a power of 2 image.

Here my code:

```
CCTexture2D *texture = CCTextureCache::sharedTextureCache()->addImage("purty_wood.png");
ccTexParams tp = { GL_LINEAR, GL_LINEAR, GL_REPEAT, GL_REPEAT};
texture->setTexParameters(&tp);
CCSprite *background = CCSprite::createWithTexture(texture, CCRectMake(0, 0, visibleSize.width, visibleSize.height));
background->setPosition( ccp( visibleSize.width/2, visibleSize.height/2 ) );
this->addChild(background, 1);
```